# Listing searchable values after pg_search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pg-search

Is there a way of getting the pg_search results from the model and not the indexing table entries? My code works, but I have to loop through the results.

```
search = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:search])

@items = Array.new
search.find_each do |result|
  @items.push(result.searchable)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multisearch will always return `PgSearch::Document` records.

If you want to query your model directly, you can define a `pg_search_scope`, e.g.:

```
pg_search_scope :custom_search, :against => [:title] # Can use multiple fields
```

And then use it with `search = Model.custom_search(params[:search])`, which will return `Model` records.

Also, a cleaner way to write your code above would be:

```
search = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:search])
@items = search.map(&:searchable)
```